# is there a single management console for multiple WSO2 Carbon based products?

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Since all WSO2 products are based on the same plattform (Carbon), I was wondering if there's a way to configure a single management console for multiple products, such as Data Service Server, Application Server, ESB, etc...

What I want to have is a common console to access, manage, and monitor multiple WSO2 products.

Any information that can lead me to my objective will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run multiple product servers you can't access them from the same management console. But you can install relevant features to a single product, so that all the services can be managed through single management console.

Ex: Install DSS features on ESB

[1]http://wso2.com/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2/
[2]http://dileepajayakody.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-features-via-feature.html
[3]http://kalpassupblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-wso2-dss-features-on.html